# Wheel Scroll View Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Does anyone know how to make this in flutter? It is a pretty common ios thing, but I tried wheeldelegatescrollview or whatever its called and didn't get the exact thing. I want it so that there is a transparent overlay, and can't figure it out. Thanks!

(The time picker beneath rest between exercises)
[image]

Comment: You mean using https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html#cupertino.CupertinoPicker.1 and setting `selectionOverlay` to `null`?

Comment: See  [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTimerPicker-class.html)

Answer (score 3):

I realized that, you can just use the Cupertino timer picker in Flutter and it literally is exactly what I want. Leaving this question up for anyone else who has the same issue